# Does Alamofire by default request for gzipped response?

Tags: ios, swift, gzip, alamofire, http-accept-encoding

I am using Alamofire for networking in my project. As my server support gzipped response. I wanted to know whether Alamofire in itself support gzip or do i need to exclusively set in its header as **["Accept-Encoding":"gzip"]**.
I tried both the cases and did not find any difference in the size of response.
So I was assuming that it requests for gzip response by default.
Any light on this topic would be useful.

Also is there a way to check for raw response with Alamofire?

Comment: Yes it does automatically. Check out this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096298/using-swift-to-handle-gzipped-containing-json-http-response

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16423166/afnetworking-enable-gzip

Comment: Thanks @SashaKozachuk.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Alamofire handle it by itself, and don't need to do anything...
You can find more here:
https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/issues/256